# How to access GET_XML_ALL_ORDERS_DATA_BY_ORDER_DATE_GENERAL (Amazon Seller Partner API)

Tags: amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

I have been able to download some reports via Amazon Seller Partner API but I can't for some others such as GET_XML_ALL_ORDERS_DATA_BY_ORDER_DATE_GENERAL. When I call get_report endpoint, the response I got has no reports to download:

```
{'errors': None,
 'headers': {'Date': 'Sat, 08 Jan 2022 19:58:29 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '14', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-RequestId': '******', 'x-amzn-RateLimit-Limit': '0.0222', 'x-amz-apigw-id': '******', 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': '****'},
 'next_token': None,
 'pagination': None,
 'payload': {'reports': []},
 'rate_limit': '0.0222'}
```

The report type I am having trouble is described at https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/references/reports-api/reporttype-values.md#order-reports

How can I resolve this? I have access to PII BTW so that's not a cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is a type of reports I need to create first.